# Filtering CSV files

Tags: csv, sed, awk, grep

I have a csv file and another text file (say file1.csv and file2.txt). The text file has one column. Now, I want to filter the csv file based on the data in the text file. For example,

```
file1.csv
-----------
1,a,b,c
2,d,e,f
3,g,d,g

file2.txt
-----------
1
3
```

I want the result to be-

```
1,a,b,c
3,g,d,g
```

Comment: Ok. I was able to solve it using simple 'grep' command. grep -f file2.txt file1.csv. I am just curious to see if there are any other ways.

Comment: Your nice simple solution will also pick up the rows `10,p,q,r` and `300,x,y,z` from `file1.csv` (not to mention `444,1,2,33`); is that OK?  If not, you need to use the `join` command, with appropriate sorts, probably (or `awk` and associative arrays, or Perl, or Python, or maybe `grep -f <(sed 's/.*/^&,/' file2.txt) file1.csv`).

Comment: You may also want to look at [csvfix](http://code.google.com/p/csvfix] for a tool to manipulate CSV files.

Comment: Aargh: I meant — [csvfix](http://code.google.com/p/csvfix).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this command:

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next};$1 in a' file2.txt file1.csv
```

Logic is simple:

```
FOR each line in 'file2.txt' and 'file1.csv'
    IF line is from 'file2.txt'
        store it to array 'a'
        CONTINUE
    ENDIF
    IF column 1 of line is in 'a'
        PRINT line
    ENDIF
ENDFOR
```

Answer (score 1):

For a solution using `awk`, see the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18347009/15168) by [kev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/348785/kev).

For an improved solution using `grep -f`, consider using `bash` [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution):

```
grep -f <(sed 's/.*/^&,/' file2.txt) file1.csv
```

This uses `sed` on the lines in `file2.txt` to put a caret at the start of each line and a comma at the end, so that when treated as a regex by (GNU?) `grep`, the patterns only match the exact field value at the start of the line.  If you don't have `bash`, you may be able to use:

```
sed 's/.*/^&,/' file2.txt | grep -f - file1.csv
```

However, not all versions of `grep` read standard input when you specify `-f -` (the version on Mac OS X doesn't, for example, but GNU `grep` does).

Alternatively, you could use the `join` command, with appropriate sorts:

```
join -o 1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4 -t, <(sort file1.csv) <(sort file2.txt)
```

If you're confident the files are already sorted, you can simplify that to just:

```
join -o 1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4 -t, file1.csv file2.txt
```

In Perl, you could use:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = 0;
my %rows;

while (<>)
{
    chomp;
    $rows{$_}++ if ($file == 0);
    if ($file == 1)
    {
        my($id) = split /,/;
        print "$_\n" if defined $rows{$id};
    }
}
continue
{
    $file = 1 if eof;
}
```

There are probably other ways to do it too; for example, you might find a use for modules such as [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3A%3ACSV).

However, this code reads each line.  If it is from the first file, then it creates an entry `$rows{$_}++` to record that the number was seen.  Order and repetition don't matter.  In the second (and subsequent) files, it splits the first comma separated field out of the line, and checks whether that number was found in the first file; if so, it prints the whole line.  The `continue` block detects when the code reaches EOF on the first file (in particular) and sets `$file = 1;` when it does.  It is isomorphic with the `awk` solution.  This is a little verbose.  There is the `-a` mode (`awk` mode), but because the two files need to be treated differently, it's a tad tricky to get it to work right.

Of these, I think the `grep -f` solution is probably the neatest as long as `file2.txt` is not too large (and I'm not sure what the limit would be — but probably surprisingly large).

For a general purpose CSV file manipulation tool, consider [csvfix](http://code.google.com/p/csvfix).

Answer (score 0):

Try the below command:

grep -F -f file2.txt file1.csv

1,a,b,c
3,g,d,g

Answer (score 0):

And for Windows Command Version:

```
findstr /G:file2.txt file1.csv > result.csv
```